# Paired $t$-test when pairing is not known and some subjects responded only in one condition

Tags: t-test, sample-size, paired-comparisons

In testing the difference between a 'pre' survey group and 'post' survey group, I have the same sample population surveyed, yet different sample sizes (fewer respondents within the 'post' group). Am I still able to do a paired *t* test?

More detail: I have 320 students. 304 responded to the pre survey and 156 of these responded to the post survey. The responses were anonymous so I can not only pull the 156 students who responded to both surveys to compare.

**Can I still do a paired *t* test to see if pre and post are significantly different, considering there are different sample sizes?**

Comment: I would either treat it as a two-sample t-test or just use the same people who responded both times.

Comment: I disagree with @StatMan 's advice to just use the same people who responded both times, because you are almost certain to get biased results: yours is a case for multiple imputation. Likewise treating the two groups as independent ignores the actual dependence existing in the before-after samples.

Comment: I disagree with @Alexis.  Multiple imputation is overkill.  Why not just use an actual method that has been built for the problem like the ones in http://www.amazon.com/Survey-Sampling-Statistics-Textbooks-Monographs/dp/0824757548

Comment: Multiple imputation validly incorporates the added uncertainty due to missing data, which are manifestly present in your case. Neither of @StatMan 's proposed solutions do this. Multiple imputation really is not that difficult to do, see for example: Schafer, J. L. (1999). Multiple imputation: a primer. *Statistical Methods in Medical Research*, 8:3–15.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

How would you have analyzed the data if the 2 sample sizes had worked out to be the same?  A paired test usually requires you to know the pairs, some form of ID that links the 2 surveys of the same person.  A truly anonymous survey will not have this information available making the paired test impossible.  Some surveys will include an arbitrary ID number that the respondent is to include both times and is (hopefully) unique to each respondent, but this has to be designed into the survey up front (and may reduce it from anonymous to confidential).

Also, are the 304 out of the 320 a random/representative sample? or could there be a bias?  Are the 156 a random/representative sample of the 304? or could there be a bias?  If those students who improved were more likely to answer the post survey than those who declined then that could greatly bias the results.

Are you planning on using a finite population correction?

These questions should be examined before the questions that you asked as they will probably have a much larger impact on your results than the bias of using an independent t-test.  It may be that your best approach is to report summary statistics and not attempt any formal inference.

***Edit***

Here is some R code that simulates some data based on the original numbers and compares results:

```r
library(MASS)

simfun <- function(r=0, d=0) {
    x <- mvrnorm(320, c(0,d), matrix( c(1,r,r,1), 2 ))
    x[ sample( 320, 16 ), 1 ] <- NA
    x[ sample( 320, 164 ), 2 ] <- NA
    c(paired = t.test( na.omit(x)[,1], na.omit(x)[,2], 
                       paired=TRUE)$p.value,
 ind1 = t.test( na.omit(x)[,1], na.omit(x)[,2] )$p.value,
    ind2 = t.test( na.omit(x[,1]), na.omit(x[,2])  )$p.value)
}


out <- replicate(10000, simfun(r=0, d=0))
out <- t(out)

pairs(out)

mean( out[,2] > out[,1] )
mean( out[,3] > out[,1] )
mean( out[,3] > out[,2] )

mean(out[,1] <= 0.05)
mean(out[,2] <= 0.05)
mean(out[,3] <= 0.05)

out <- replicate(10000, simfun(r=0.7, d=0.2))
out <- t(out)

pairs(out)

mean( out[,2] > out[,1] )
mean( out[,3] > out[,1] )
mean( out[,3] > out[,2] )

mean(out[,1] <= 0.05)
mean(out[,2] <= 0.05)
mean(out[,3] <= 0.05)
```

Running this code (and you can change to different values of `r` and `d`) shows that when there is no correlation and no difference then all 3 tests give the correct type I error rate.  With correlation and no difference the proper paired test still gives the correct type I error rate and the other 2 give an error rate below what is specified (conservative).  When there is a difference then the paired test has the most power.

So if you are happy with all the assumptions about representative samples and independence between responses and likelihood of responding, then you could use an independent t-test (even though you don't have independence) and just realize that the results will be conservative, p-values to large, confidence interval too wide, on average.  If the test is significant you can be confident in a significant difference.  The problem comes with p-values that are a little large than $\alpha$, they could represent a significant difference with inflated p-value.

Comment: Hi Greg,
Thanks so much for your ideas @GregSnow. I do not have any to match the students between pre and post surveys. No arbetrary ID or names. There is no bias that students who improved would be more likely to respond to the post test. So, I realize I cannot use a paired t-test, but the dependence of my samples (same population) doesn't allow me to do an unpaired t-test either. Here lies my problem. What test can I do to test my null hypothesis that the % respondents answering yes in the pre is equal to those answering yes in the post? I am not aware of a finite population correction

Comment: @Jules You *can* use a paired *t* test with multiple imputation.

Comment: @Alexis, how would he do a paired test when he does not know **any** of the pairs?  I can see using the relationship in known pairs to estimate correlation and therefore impute the missing post survey, but without knowing the pairs to begin with you would need to make pretty strong assumptions about the relationship.

Comment: Oh, I see. I had misunderstood and thought that the IDs were available (as in for pre-score 23.7, the paired post score was 51.1 or whatever) for respondents who completed both pre and post observations.

Comment: @Jules, if the pre-post correlation is positive (most reasonable assumption) and you ignore it and use the unpaired/independent t-test then it will be conservative, i.e. the p-value will be larger (on average) than if you had the pairing information and a confidence interval would be wider, so a significant result will still be meaningful.

Comment: Alexis - thanks for the suggestion about multiple imputation. I'll consider it, but I'm still concerned with its validity without being about a pair
@GregSnow and others- Do you have any suggestions of other statistical tests that I can do besides a paired t that will meet my conditions? Without knowing the student's to pair, it seems not to fit. I appreciate your concerns about the biases, but I have to work around these, and without getting into too much detail of the study, do not think that they will be a concern.

Comment: @Jules can you make clear if, for respondents answering *both* pre and post questions, you know the pairing (i.e. which pre score goes with which post score)?

Comment: @Alexis - I do not know the pairing of which pre score goes with which post score

Comment: @Jules Drat and confound! That *is* a tough nut to crack! Regardless, whichever analysis you undertake (if there *is* a reasonable one), multiple imputation is viable: you probabilistically impute a bunch of complete data sets (i.e reality 5 to 10), conduct your analysis on each, and the create average results with standard errors for those results using a special formula (see the Shaffer citation).

Comment: @GregSnow - So, you are suggesting a 'standard,; unpaired independent t-test? I had considered this. Is there any concern in using this because my samples are not two separate groups? Some of the students are in both pre and post, some students are only in pre and some are only in post - I have no way of knowing which fall into these three categories. Thus, my samples are dependent, not from two independent groups as a t-test would require... right?

Comment: @Alexis - thanks for the suggestion. I don't have access to the Shaffer paper, but was looking at this: Cox et al. 2014. Working with Missing Data in Higher Education Research: A Primer
and Real-World Example. The Review of Higher Education. This paper suggests multiple imputation as the first and most reliable step in working around missing data. I don't have the means to pursue this step today, and was looking for a quicker and dirtier statistical test in the meantime...Thanks again for your help

Comment: @GregSnow - Wow! Wonderful! I really appreciate the time you took on the R-code. I'll modify as needed, but I agree that this suggests that I can do an independent t-test as long as I report all of my assumptions. Thanks so much for your help!